# Resume Replication after restoring publication database

Tags: sql-server-2008, transactional-replication

We are using Transactional Replication. I have publisher database called D1 and subscriber database D2. D1 is getting log shipped at the DR environment.  we have 'sync with Backup' option is enable on publisher (D1). Now my data has been backed up but it doesn't go to the distributer for some reason and D1 got crashed. We are restoring Backed up database on different server and setup the publication and subscription again.

So whatever data has been not gone to the distributer database will be now replicated or not ?

if we delete the publication and delete the D1 database and restore it from DR environment with 'Preserve the Replication Settings'  it doesn't replicate the data although publication is already there ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IS this OK? 
this is from another site:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlsakthi/archive/2012/03/14/re-configure-replication-after-restoring-publication-database-from-backup-replication-scenario.aspx

Script the Publication -> Drop Subscriptions -> Drop Publication -> Re-create them

You can use "Sync with Backup" to avoid these scenarios but at the expense of high log reader latency depending on the frequency of the log backup at the publication database. Read more about "sync with backup" option from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152560.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your response Bisjom. It really helped.